Why people write that IEnumerable filters data from within memory while IQueryable does it on the server side?
There are many topics on stackoverflow:
When should I use IEnumerable and when IQueryable?
What is the difference between IQueryable<T> and IEnumerable<T>?
When should I use IEnumerable and when IQueryable?
What's the difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable
These posts claim that IEnumerable filters data from within memory while IQueryable does it on the server side. But I have found this to be inaccurate.
IEnumerable filters data from within memory only if we split a query!
For example, if I use IEnumerable like this
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = context.Customers.Where(c => c.FirstName.StartsWith("J")).Take(5).ToList(); 

it gives a correct query with filter top(5):
select top(5) * from Customers WHERE FirstName like 'j%';

This means that Where and Take are both encoded into the query and run on the server, which contradicts what the posts above claim.
On the other hand, if I split the query:
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = context.Customers.Where(c => c.FirstName.StartsWith("J")); 
var result = customers.Take(5).ToList(); //the filter is in a different line of code

it gives a query without top(5):
select * from Customers WHERE FirstName like 'j%';

which means the Take(5) part is executed in memory.
Why do people still claim that IEnumerable filters data from within memory while IQueryable does it on the server side?

You are casting the IQueryable<Customer> to IEnumerable<Customer> which forces any subsequent operations to run in memory. If you let the type stay as IQueryable<Customer> then you'll see that it all happens on the database.

People are right. Queryable is server-side and Enumerable is in memory.

@Enigmativity Is this really the correct duplicate (or even a duplicate at all)? The duplicate target is mentioned in the question, and OP is clearly confused by it. The problem is not about IQueryable vs IEnumerable, but how extension method overload resolution works.

@AleksanderChelpski I have tried to make the question clearer. If that is not what you wanted to ask and/or I have misunderstood, please rollback.


And everywhere people write that IEnumerable filters data from within memory while IQueryable does it on the server side.

When we say "IEnumerable does this and that" or "IQueryable does this and that", we are not talking about the type the variable that you are assigning the result to.
  IEnumerable<Customer> customers = ...
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//not about this

We are talking about the set of LINQ operators that one is using. Enumerable declares LINQ operators that operate on IEnumerable<T>, whereas Queryable declares LINQ operators that operate on IQueryable<T>. The former operators operate in memory, while the latter operators would get translated into SQL and run on the database.
In the first example, where you did not "split" the query, context.Customers is a IQueryable (presumably). The Where, Take, and ToList that you call are all declared in Queryable. The fact that you declared customers to be of type IEnumerable<Customer> is irrelevant. You are not actually "using" IEnumerable here - you are not calling the methods declared in Enumerable.
In the second example, Take is not called on an IQueryable. It is called on customers, of type IEnumerable<Customer>, as you have declared. As a result, you end up calling Take that is declared in Enumerable, so the Take part does not get translated to SQL.
Note that the LINQ operators are all extension methods, so there is no dynamic dispatch - which Take gets called (Enumerable.Take or Queryable.Take) depends on the compile-time type of the expression on which you have called it. The fact that customers actually stores an instance of some type that implements IQueryable<T> is irrelevant.

@Servy I think you misunderstood the question. They misunderstood how they are different, and came to a wrong conclusion. They didn't ask "why people use one instead of the other". They asked why people state something that (they believe) "exacly isn't true", and I explained why that is correct and how they misunderstood.

@Servy This is someone who read the linked posts, misunderstood them, and ran some code that contradicts their incorrect understanding, presumes the posts they read are incorrect, and asks "why did they say those incorrect things"?

latter operators translates the query into SQL - these operators do not translate anything, they record their calls in IQueryable.Expression.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Yeah, I didn't want to mention anything about expression trees because IMO that is distracting from the point, so I ended up something inaccurate. How about "would get translated into SQL"?
